# Can not find custom method in build.gradle with MissingMethodException

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I got an error when I tried to call a custom method in `build.gradle`.

In `build.gradle` file:

```
def func() {
    String str = "hello world!"
    str
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        String str = func()
        println "$str"

        ...... // Other code
    }
}
```

The error I got is as followed:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method func() for arguments [] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1c86d7b4.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything insight the buildscript{} closures have a different scope. I'm a groovy noop and can't really explain why - maybe someone can add this. But what you can do to achive your goal is to define `func` within `buildscript`:

```
buildscript {
    func =  {
        String str = "hello world!"
        str
    }

    dependencies {
        str = func()
        println "$str"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```